# Unhandled exception with "Configuring using the "ninja.exe" CMake generator"

Tags: cmake, ninja, nanoframework

I'm trying to compile nanoframework for MCU STM32L476.
I followed the getting-started-guides pages, but at the VS Code setup, after the configuration of json files, I have this unattended result when I'm selecting CMake configuration :

---

- [cms-client] Configuring using the "ninja.exe" CMake generator
- [rollbar] Unhandled exception: Unhandled Promise rejection: Changing build variant [cmake-server] Failed to activate protocol version: Generator "ninja.exe" not supported. {}
- [cms-client] Configuring using the "ninja.exe" CMake generator
- [rollbar] Unhandled exception: Unhandled Promise rejection: setVariant [cmake-server] Failed to activate protocol version: Generator "ninja.exe" not supported. {}

  ---

I tried the lastest version of CMAKE (3.15.2) and NINJA (1.9.0) and the previous version of each (respectively 3.14.6 and 1.8.2).
I also tried the Win32 and x64 version of Cmake.

And I tried the mix of all version !

Comment: Looks like you inadvertently set the Generator to the name of the ninja executable. Try to call `cmake -G "Ninja" <your additional parameters>`

Comment: You're right ! I had a mistake in my "settings.json", the template in the nanoframework is bad ! Problem is now solved. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `.\.vscode\settings.json` change `ninja.exe` to `Ninja`, e.g. mine looks now like this:

```
{
    "cmake.preferredGenerators": [
        "Ninja"
    ],
    "cmake.generator": "Ninja",
    "cmake.useCMakeServer" : true,
    "cmake.autoRestartBuild" : true,
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM":"C:/Esp32_Tools/ninja/ninja.exe"
    },
    "cmake.cmakePath": "c:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": false,
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "vector-of-bool.cmake-tools"
}
```